# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:cert.CertPathValidatorException:Trust anchor for certification path not found -error in Cordova for Android

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have integrated Cordova-plugin-client-certificate-addictic in a Cordova app. It’s working great in iPhone but when I run app on Android it’s not working.
Error message I am getting in Android is:
java.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Should I need to do some additional stuff for Android, I searched on stack overflow and on github nothing worked so far. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various solutions from various post, it did not work.
Then i was start doing hit and trial method and one of them worked, below is the detail for same:

open project in android studio and Open the ClientCertificate.java from src folder of plugin.

step 1:go to line#60 and comment this line // InputStream astream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
and put this new line: InputStream astream = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(p12path);

step2: go to line# // p12path = a.getString(0);
and put this new line#  p12path = "www/" + a.getString(0);